# Schedule Generator in python

Tags: python, scheduling

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWwJO.png)

I want to make a program in python That receive a costume number (Which should be power of two like 4,8,16,32 ...) from user and program start to make a output like the table's content(link in UP) (n teams match schedule in (n-1) weeks and also we'll have n(n-1) matches at all).
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't post links to examples but include the example within your question.

Comment: Also from your question I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Could you post a minimal reproducible example please? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It will be much easier for us to help

Comment: what did you try? where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/)** module here:

1. Write `pip install tabulate` in the terminal.
2. This code would work:

   ```
    import math
    from tabulate import tabulate

    costume_number = int(input("Enter Costume number"))
    try:
        if math.log(costume_number, 2).is_integer():
            table_list = [["", "week", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"], ["team", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"], []] #etc.. please continue writing whatever the data is.
            print(tabulate(table_list))
    except TypeError:
        print(costume_number + " is not a costume number.")
   ```

Comment: But... The question is how to generate the data to fill the table, not just print it as a table... You didn't answer the main part of the question...

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to making the Frame of the table but still I have problem in algorithm(for making the matches schedule ) .

```
import math
from tabulate import tabulate
def is_power_of_two(team_num):
    return (math.ceil(math.log2(team_num)) == math.floor(math.log2(team_num)))
team_num_check = False
while (team_num_check == False):
       team_num = int(input('How many teams does this leage have ?\n'))
       if(is_power_of_two(team_num)):
           team_num_check = True
       else:
            print("Enter a valid number due to rules of league.")
week_num = (team_num - 1)
week_counter = 1
team_counter = 0
table = []
while team_counter <= team_num:
      table.append([team_counter])
      while week_counter <= week_num:
           table[team_counter].append(week_counter)
           week_counter+=1
      team_counter+=1
print(tabulate(table,tablefmt="github"))
```